# Can't seem to get three.js to rotate correctly when using react and three.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I am using react on typescript, and trying to figure out how `three.js` works but have stumbled on a few problems regarding camera rotation, and in general camera movement

OnComponentDidMount loads my fake data and begins to draw. I manage to draw the image (not correctly but i draw it none the less)

I have tried to add rotations by using OrbitControls, but this has been an issue, as the image i render, cant be interacted with: I cant zoom rotate or anything else.

A secondary issue is that the way i am rendering in the component feels very "hacky", and is not how i would like it to render.

A lot of the work is inspired from "https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_normals.html" - Currently i am simple trying to get react and `three.js` working together in a react environment, and not very focused on the actual data that is rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three-orbitcontrols-ts';

export interface IMapperState {
    canvasReady: boolean;
}

export default class Drawer extends React.Component<{}, IMapperState> {
private map: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
private camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
private scene: THREE.Scene;

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.map = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    this.state = { canvasReady: false }
}

private draw = (data: any) => {
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcce0ff);
    this.camera.position.set(10, 10, 30);
    this.map.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);

    data.box.forEach(coord => {
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(coord.x, coord.z, coord.y)
        const wallImage = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ opacity: 0.1, color: "red" })

        const wall = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, wallImage);

        wall.position.setX(coord.x);
        wall.position.setY(coord.y);
        this.scene.add(wall)
    });

    const controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera);

    this.map.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    this.map.gammaInput = true;
    this.map.gammaOutput = true;
    this.map.shadowMap.enabled = true;

    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize, false);

    this.setState({ canvasReady: true })
}

private onWindowResize = () => {
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.map.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
}

public componentDidMount() {
    const mockData = {
        box: [
            { x: 10, y: 30, z: 100 }
        ]
    };
    this.draw(mockData);
}

render(): JSX.Element {
    if (this.state.canvasReady) {
        if (document.getElementById("threeJsTest")) {
            var el: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("threeJsTest");
            if (el) {
                el.appendChild(this.map.domElement);
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <div id="threeJsTest" />
    );
}
```

}

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "threejsreactdemo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "23.3.10",
    "@types/node": "10.12.18",
    "@types/react": "16.7.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.11",
    "@types/three": "^0.93.13",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "three": "^0.99.0",
    "three-orbitcontrols-ts": "^0.1.2",
    "typescript": "3.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Actual results: I cant interact with the image and my render method is not very pretty.

Wanted result: Hopefully i cleaner render method - and the ability to zoom / rotate the rendered image - in react: typescript

Comment: If you want to use three.js with React you can check out ReactVR. https://facebook.github.io/react-360/